# Redirect all links in a Folder to index.php with GET variable(using htaccess)?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

I don't know if it is possible, but I think it is. I've never worked with htaccess, so I don't even know how to search it.
I want to redirect all links inside a folder to `index.php` passing the file name as a GET variable.

For example:
`localhost/folder/file-123` redirects to `localhost/index.php?file=file-123`.

I didn't found anything near this in StackOverflow, but if it was already answered, just link it please.

Thank you =)

Comment: [Give it a try](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=htaccess+redirect+tutorial) and then come back and ask for help once you have at least given it a try yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation that comes with the apache http server's rewriting module is of *excellent* quality and comes with great examples. You will also find the answer to your question in there.

You will probably want to tweek this to your specific needs, but the following should point you into the correct direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?folder/(.*)$ /index.php?file=$1 [END,QSA]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Worked, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess` files works the roughly the same way than `<Location>` directives, but they actually apply to the directory they're stored in. Also, they can be modified without having to restart the server, which indeed is useful for website owners that don't have a access to the global configuration file (e.g. hosting services).

If you want your redirection to be totally transparent from the client's side, refer to [arkascha's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56175045/7426932)

If however, you wish a true HTTP redirection (automatic, but updating the client's address bar), you can stick to `Redirect` and [RedirectMatch](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch) directives, which are meant for this, and are easier than `RewriteRule` even though this latter one is not so complicated.